# Order of preprocessing steps in a binary classification problem

Tags: classification, data-transformation, outliers, normalization, dimensionality-reduction

I have these stages (ordered) for `preprocessing` in my binary classification problem.

1. Dividing data based on criteria (class1 and class2 databases)
2. Outlier detection `(removing X - mean(X) >= 2*std(X) based on every feature)`
3. data balancing ( in every year - I have financial data and I'm balancing data based on some features of samples - database consisted of 5 years and I'm doing this step separately in every year - now i have equal samples in every class)
4. Data normalization
5. Dimension reduction (`PCA` etc.)

Is this ordering true? You know that `normalization`, `dimension reduction` and `outlier detection` generate some parameters that we must apply these parameters to new database that will import to our created database in future( out sample in real using of the model raw data without any balancing)
. I know that `outlier detection` should be before `normalization`. Is this two `preprocessing` steps (`outlier detection` and `normalization`) should be before `balancing` of after `balancing` of data?

Comment: I would personally omit steps 3 and 5, as standard methods don't really need either of them (SVM, RF, ANN) and removing information is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I found in the articles (related to my problem) that when we don't balance data (suppose that in raw data set we have 1000 samples from class 1 and 60 samples from class2) , this will effect type 1 and type 2 errors of model (sensitivity and specificity in binary classification model)

Comment: That depends entirely on what method you use.

Comment: I'm using Neural network (`patternnet` function), `SVM (Libsvm)` and `extreme learning machine` for binary classification. (`MATLAB`)

Comment: use class-weighted SVM (higher C for the minority class). That approach is almost always better than subsampling the majority class, which is what you probably do now. In LIBSVM, you can do that with the `-wX` flags where `X` represents the class label.

Comment: We don't need any changing in neural network? (specially `patternnet`)? + my samples are companies and my features are financial rations. There are different size of companies with different range of financial rations in my data-set. With balancing I was balancing data-set based on companies sizes, so with this new information what is your suggestion about this problem?

Comment: + When I desabled data balancing, I have 182 samples from `class 1` and 1409 samples from `class 2`. The accuracy of test data of class 1 (5-fold cross validation) is 70% but the the accuracy of class 2 is near 98% ! (with neural network)